# Delete/nullify index setting using Nest

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

How do I delete a specific elastic index settings or set it to null using Elasticsearch Nest 7.6. I have the following 2 shard allocation filters on an index:

```
"settings": {
    "index": {
        "routing": {
            "allocation": {
                "include": {
                    "phase_id": "warm"
                },
                "require": {
                    "phase_id": "hot"
                }
            }
        },
    }
}
```

I need to either remove the `require` setting completely or set the `require.phase_id` to null.

So far I've tried the following:

```
        var resp = await _client.Indices.UpdateSettingsAsync(Indices.Index(warmIndices),
            updateIndexSetting => updateIndexSetting
                .IndexSettings(indexSetting => indexSetting
                    .Setting("index.routing.allocation.require.phase_id", null)
                    .Setting("index.routing.allocation.include.phase_id", "warm")));
```

Only issue with this is that the `require` settings doesn't get assigned null. Also read somewhere on stack overflow that passing `false` would set the settings to `null` but it doesn't.